# How to find the source of IE8 Internet explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-8, xss, cross-domain

One of my customers gets "Internet explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting" error on her website on IE8.

The page has several ajax calls to the same domain + calls to standard js files outside the domain such as google analytics.

How can I detect which call from the browser is actually causing it?

Comment: Causing what? What is your question?

Comment: How can I detect which call from the browser is actually causing the IE8 error message described above.

Answer (score -1):

You can see your request and other error information with the help of **[IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)**. See its documentation for more info about it. It is addon of IE, once you install it, it will be integrated into IE.

Comment: I have tried to find the reason with IE developer toolbar, but it does not seem to help identify which of the calls is causing the specific error.

Comment: @Nir: did you have a look at its documentation, it does provide a way to see the requests.

Comment: I'm using debugbar to see the requests. I see ajax requests but they are from the same domain + a call to google analytics. I need to find a way to get to the exact request that is causing it.